# Use view pager2 to load 3 weburls in advance before displaying them and they should loop around if there is no more entries

Tags: kotlin, android-webview, android-viewpager2

I am working on an Android application where I want to implement a ViewPager2 to display web content. Specifically, I want to preload three web URLs in advance to ensure a smooth user experience. Additionally, I would like the ViewPager2 to loop around seamlessly. If there is no more entries it should push which was previously on 1 and pop which is already shown.

I have implemented a solution, and below is the relevant code for the WebAdControllerFragment and associated fragments. However, I'm facing issues with the preloading mechanism and looping functionality.

WebAdControllerFragment.kt

class WebAdControllerFragment : Fragment() {

```
companion object {
    private const val WEB_URLS_KEY = "webUrls"

    fun newInstance(playlistEntries: List<PlaylistEntry>): WebAdControllerFragment {
        return WebAdControllerFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putStringArrayList(
                    WEB_URLS_KEY,
                    ArrayList(playlistEntries.flatMap { it.webUrlEntries!!.map { webEntry -> webEntry.url } })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
private lateinit var webUrls: List<String>

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_ad_controller, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

    arguments?.let {
        webUrls = it.getStringArrayList(WEB_URLS_KEY) ?: emptyList()
        setupViewPager()
    }
}

private fun setupViewPager() {
    val pagerAdapter = WebPagerAdapter(requireActivity(), webUrls)
    viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
}

private inner class WebPagerAdapter(activity: FragmentActivity, private val webUrls: List<String>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = webUrls.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val webUrl = webUrls[position]
        return WebAdFragment.newInstance(webUrl, clearWebCache = false, enableCache = true)
    }
}
```

}

Playlistadloopactivity.kt

private fun loadNextAd(hardRefresh: Boolean = false) {
if (this.isDestroyed || !isActivityRunning) {
return
}
currentAd?.let { currentAd ->
if (currentAdIndex >= 0 && playlist.entries.isNotEmpty())
AppLogger.debug(
AppLogger.AD_LOOP,
"CurrentAdIndex: $currentAdIndex playlistId:${screen.playlistId} entryId:${playlist.entries[currentAdIndex].id} duration:${playlist.entries[currentAdIndex].durationInSeconds} screenId:${screen.id}",
)

```
        if (currentAd.isAdSlot && (currentAd.campaigns?.size ?: 0) > 0) {
            currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = determineAdSlotIndex(currentAd)
            currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex =
                if (currentAd.campaigns?.firstOrNull()?.slotExposure?.toFloat() == 1f) {
                    saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id, 0)
                    currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 0
                    0
                } else
                    lastPlayedAdSlotPosition(
                        currentAd.id
                    ).let {
                        when (it) {
                            -1, 1 -> {
                                saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id, 0)
                                currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 0
                                0
                            }

                            0 -> {
                                saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id, 1)
                                currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 1
                                1
                            }

                            else -> {
                                saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id ?: -1, 0)
                                currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 0
                                0
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }
        when {
            (!currentAd.isAdSlot && (currentAd.isWebSlot || currentAd.isMenu || currentAd.isIPaws)) -> {
                applyResizing()
                var webUrl = currentAd.weburl?.url
                val differenceLastMenuRefresh =
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentAd.lastRefreshTime) / 1000
                var clearWebCache = false

                if (differenceLastMenuRefresh >= 0) {
                    clearWebCache = true
                    currentAd.lastRefreshTime =
                        System.currentTimeMillis()
                            .plus(60.times(MINUTE_REFRESH_MENUAPP).times(1000))
                    if (currentAd.isMenu || currentAd.isEnabledForWebCache()) {
                        webUrl += Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING
                    }
                }
                if ((currentAd.isMenu || currentAd.isEnabledForWebCache()) && webUrl?.contains(
                        Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING
                    )
                        ?.not() == true && (hardRefresh || hardRefreshMenuItems.contains(
                        currentAd.id
                    ))
                ) {
                    hardRefreshMenuItems.remove(currentAd.id)
                    webUrl += Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING
                }
                webUrl = buildWebUrl(currentAd, hardRefresh)
                webUrl?.let {
                    MainScope().launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        if (!shouldSkipWebUrlLoad(webUrl, currentAd)) {
                            runOnUiThread {
                                showWebView(webUrl, clearWebCache = true, MINUTE_REFRESH_MENUAPP)
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInternetAvailable().not()
                            && playListEntries.count() == 1
                            && supportFragmentManager.fragments.filterIsInstance<WebAdFragment>()
                                .isEmpty().not()
                            && hardRefresh.not()
                        ) {
                            return@launch
                        } else {
                            if (Lifecycle.State.RESUMED == lifecycle.currentState)
                                runOnUiThread {
                                    showWebView(it, clearWebCache, MINUTE_REFRESH_MENUAPP)
                                }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            else -> {
                if (currentAd.isVideoSlot()) {
                    applyResizing()
                    playVideo()
                } else {
                    applyResizing()
                    val urlToLoad =
                        if (currentAd.isAdSlot) {
                            currentAd.campaigns?.get(currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex)?.media?.hash
                                ?: Constants.EMPTY_LOOP_IMAGE_URL
                        } else currentAd.media.hash
                    if (urlToLoad != previousUrl || totalScheduledPlayListItems(playlist.entries) > 1) {
                        previousUrl = urlToLoad
                    }
                    showImages()
                    ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun determineAdSlotIndex(currentAd: PlaylistEntry): Int {
    return if (currentAd.campaigns?.firstOrNull()?.slotExposure?.toFloat() == 1f) {
        saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id, 0)
        currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 0
        0
    } else {
        when (lastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id)) {
            -1, 1 -> {
                saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id, 0)
                currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 0
                0
            }
            0 -> {
                saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id, 1)
                currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 1
                1
            }
            else -> {
                saveLastPlayedAdSlotPosition(currentAd.id ?: -1, 0)
                currentAd.currentAdSlotIndex = 0
                0
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun buildWebUrl(currentAd: PlaylistEntry, hardRefresh: Boolean): String {
    var webUrl = currentAd.weburl?.url

    val differenceLastMenuRefresh =
        (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentAd.lastRefreshTime) / 1000

    if (differenceLastMenuRefresh >= 0) {
        currentAd.lastRefreshTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            .plus(60.times(MINUTE_REFRESH_MENUAPP).times(1000))
        if (currentAd.isMenu || currentAd.isEnabledForWebCache()) {
            webUrl += Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING
        }
    }
    if ((currentAd.isMenu || currentAd.isEnabledForWebCache()) && webUrl?.contains(
            Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING
        )
            ?.not() == true && (hardRefresh || hardRefreshMenuItems.contains(
            currentAd.id
        ))
    ) {
        hardRefreshMenuItems.remove(currentAd.id)
        webUrl += Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING
    }
    return webUrl ?: ""
}

private fun shouldSkipWebUrlLoad(webUrl: String, currentAd: PlaylistEntry): Boolean {
    var hardRefresh: Boolean = false
    return !isInternetAvailable()
            && playlist.entries.count() == 1
            && supportFragmentManager.fragments.filterIsInstance<WebAdFragment>().isEmpty()
            && !hardRefresh
}
```

and here is my webAdfragment class

class WebAdFragment : Fragment() {

```
companion object {

    const val CLEAR_WEB_CACHE = "clearWebCache"
    const val ENABLE_CACHE = "enableCache"
    const val URL = "url"
    fun newInstance(url: String, clearWebCache: Boolean, enableCache: Boolean) =
        WebAdFragment().apply {
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString(URL, url)
            args.putBoolean(CLEAR_WEB_CACHE, clearWebCache)
            args.putBoolean(ENABLE_CACHE, enableCache)
            arguments = args
        }
}

private lateinit var url: String
private var clearWebCache: Boolean = false
private var enableCache: Boolean = false
lateinit var binding: WebAdFragmentBinding
val networkDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    url = arguments?.getString(URL) ?: ""
    clearWebCache = arguments?.getBoolean(CLEAR_WEB_CACHE, false) ?: false
    enableCache = arguments?.getBoolean(ENABLE_CACHE, false) ?: false
}

fun getUrl(): String {
    return url
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return WebAdFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).let {
        binding = it
        it.root
    }
}

fun onInternet(isAvailable: Boolean) {
    binding.wifiDisconnectedView.isGone = isAvailable
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.webView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK)
    setupWebViewConfigurations()

    loadUrl(url, clearWebCache)
}

private fun setupWebViewConfigurations() {
    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(binding.webView, true)

    if (enableCache) {
        binding.webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
        AppLogger.info(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, "WEB VIEW cache enabled")
        clearCacheTimeoutObserver?.cancel()
        scheduleToClearCacheAndHardRefresh(
            (activity as? PlaylistAdLoopActivity)?.currentAd?.lastRefreshTime?.let { System.currentTimeMillis() - it }?.absoluteValue
                ?: return
        )
    }

    binding.webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
    binding.webView.addHtml5Support()

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
    }
    binding.webView.webChromeClient = webChromeClient

    webViewClient?.let {
        binding.webView.webViewClient = it
    }
}

private fun loadFileInWebView(it: String) {
    binding.webView.loadUrl("file://$it")
}


var isCached = false
var clearCacheTimeoutObserver: Job? = null

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (url.contains("youtube"))
        loadUrl(url, clearWebCache)
}

private fun scheduleToClearCacheAndHardRefresh(_cacheTimeout: Long) {
    clearCacheTimeoutObserver = MainScope().launch(networkDispatcher) {
        AppLogger.info(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, "Time until cache expires ${Date(_cacheTimeout)}.")
        delay(_cacheTimeout)
        (activity as? PlaylistAdLoopActivity)?.let {
                playlistAdLoopActivity ->
            playlistAdLoopActivity.triggerWebPageDownload(
                url,
                this@WebAdFragment.url.replace(
                    Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING,
                    ""
                ).hashCode().absoluteValue.toString()
            )
            MainScope().launch {
                val currentAd=playlistAdLoopActivity.currentAd
                loadUrl(url.let {
                    if (it.contains(Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING)
                            .not() && (currentAd?.isMenu == true || currentAd?.isEnabledForWebCache() == true))
                        url = "$it${Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING}"
                    url
                }, true)
                val cacheRefreshTime =
                    playlistAdLoopActivity.MINUTE_REFRESH_MENUAPP.times(60).times(1000)
                //Reset last cache time
                playlistAdLoopActivity.currentAd?.lastRefreshTime =
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + cacheRefreshTime
                scheduleToClearCacheAndHardRefresh(cacheRefreshTime)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if (url.contains("youtube"))
        url = url.replace(Constants.YOUTUBE_RESTART_STRING, "")
}

fun loadUrl(url: String, clearWebCache: Boolean) {
    AppLogger.info(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW,"WEB VIEW URL: $url")
    if (url.isEmpty())
        clearCacheTimeoutObserver?.cancel()
    if (clearWebCache) {
        MainScope().launch(networkDispatcher) {
            if (isInternetAvailable()) {
                MainScope().launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    kotlin.runCatching {
                        clearWebViewCache()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    binding.webView.loadUrl(url)
}

private fun clearWebViewCache() {
    try {
        AppLogger.info(
            AppLogger.WEB_VIEW,
            "WEB VIEW refreshed with stack \n${Exception("Cache cleared").stackTraceToString()}"
        )
        context?.removeWebCacheFolder()
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        AppLogger.err(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, ex.toString())
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    clearCacheTimeoutObserver?.cancel()
}

private var webViewClient:WebViewClient? = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onUnhandledKeyEvent(view: WebView?, event: KeyEvent?) {
        if (event != null) {
            (activity as PlaylistAdLoopActivity).onKeyDown(event.keyCode, event)
        }
        super.onUnhandledKeyEvent(view, event)
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        if (view?.progress == 100 && context != null) {
            view.evaluateJavascript(getString(R.string.get_html_javascript_snippet)) {
                MainScope().launch(networkDispatcher) {
                    val html = it.replace("\\u003C", "<").let {
                        it.substring(1).substring(0, it.length - 2).replace("\\\"", "\"")
                    }
                    if (html.contains(
                            FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
                                .getString(STRINGS_PREVENT_WEB_CACHE_FOR).toRegex()
                        ).not()
                        && URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(url)
                    ) {
                        val folderNameForCacheOfUrl = this@WebAdFragment.url.replace(
                            Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING,
                            ""
                        ).hashCode().absoluteValue.toString()
                        val previousStatus = context?.getWebContentDownloadStatus(
                            folderNameForCacheOfUrl
                        )
                        if (previousStatus != WebCacheStatus.DOWNLOADED)
                            (activity as? PlaylistAdLoopActivity)?.let { playlistAdLoopActivity ->
                                playlistAdLoopActivity.triggerWebPageDownload(
                                    url ?: return@launch,
                                    folderNameForCacheOfUrl
                                )

                            }
                    }
                    if (html.contains(
                            FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
                                .getString(CLEAR_WEB_CACHE_FOR).toRegex()
                        )
                    ) {
                        MainScope().launch { clearWebViewCache() }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onReceivedError(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?,
        error: WebResourceError?
    ) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
        context?.let { context ->
            val cacheableURL = url.replace(Constants.MENU_REFRESH_STRING, "")
            val cacheFile = File(context.getCachedFilePath(cacheableURL))

            if (isCached.not()) {
                AppLogger.debug(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW,"Cache file path ${cacheFile.path} url: $url")
                if (cacheFile.exists()) {
                    AppLogger.debug(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, "Cached file found.")
                    loadFileInWebView(context.getCachedFilePath(cacheableURL))
                } else {
                    AppLogger.debug(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, "Cached file not found.")
                }
            } else AppLogger.debug(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, "Showing built-in cache.")
        }
    }

    override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
        AppLogger.info(AppLogger.WEB_VIEW, "Page visible: $url")
        isCached = true
    }
}

private val webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage?): Boolean {
        Log.d(
            "WebViewMessage", "${consoleMessage?.message()} -- From line " +
                    "${consoleMessage?.lineNumber()} of ${consoleMessage?.sourceId()}"
        )
        return true
    }
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    webViewClient = null
}
```

}